# Will a feed through on and off switch work with a fluorescent light?

Tags: lighting, fluorescent

We have a fluorescent light mounted above the kitchen sink.  The on/off switch is on the light fixture and it's hard to reach.  Will a feed through on and off switch work with a fluorescent light?

Comment: What do you mean by "feed through on and off switch"? Are you intending to install a wall switch? Is this a plug in light and you want to put a switch in the cord? More details will help immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that *should* be just fine. Most switches on fixtures - whether a rocker or pushbutton or pull chain - simply switch the hot wire closed (on)/open (off). If that's the case, you can install an ordinary switch in the hot wire going to the light.

**However**, I have had some old fluorescent light fixtures with a pushbutton switch where the switch would be held on for a couple of seconds to start the light - literally triggering the fluorescent starter. On **most** fluorescent fixtures, the starter and ballast all magically work together, in which case an external switch will work just fine.

Comment: I agree the push button was acting like a starter. Other than that type of fixture it should work. I don’t see a reason to close the question is good enough to get a answer.